# Main domain redirect but not the subdomains

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https, subdomain

I have a example.net domain (no ssl). I would like to redirect this domain to https://anotherdomain.com. However I would like to keep the subdomains not redirected and continue to work as sub.example.net(no ssl).

How can I manage this? Thank you.

Kind regards

Comment: What web server?

Comment: sub domains are actually domains. Each subdomain has to configured separately. If you do not configure thme to redirect, those will keep pointing to where those were.